# Typescript: how to loop over an object of interface, without typescript errors?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I tried to solve this in typescript playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play. The code is below. You can paste the code and see the same errors.

As seen in the code, I understand the basic use of interface as a function argument. The example is function createPractitioner.

However what I cannot wrap my head around is how to define a function and interface or type  where I pass the arguments to the loop function createPractitioners, and I'd like to convert the dictionary practitioners to array and loop over it.

***This code is OK and the values are logged, but typescript returns***

Argument of type '{ first: { email: string; firstName: string; }; second: { email: string; firstName: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(PractitionerData | undefined)[]'.

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'first' does not exist in type '(PractitionerData | undefined)[]'

***how to avoid this?***

```
interface PractitionerData {
  firstName: string;
  lastName?: string;
  password?: string;
  email: string;
}

class TestClass {
    constructor() {
    }

    createPractitioner(data: Partial<PractitionerData> = {}) {
        console.log("in function createPractitioner")
        console.log(data.email)
        console.log(data.firstName)
    }

    createPractitioners(practitionerData: Partial<PractitionerData[]>) {
        console.log("in function createPractitioners")

        // const dataExtracted = Object.values(practitionerData);
        // console.log(dataExtracted)
        for (const prac of practitionerData) {
            console.log(prac.email)
            console.log(prac.firstName)
        }
    }
}   

console.log("TEST")

///////// works
let practitionerEmail;
let practitionerName;
practitionerEmail = "email1233@fake.com";
practitionerName = "JAKE";

let practitioners
let practitioners2


practitioners = {
    first: {
        email: "email4@fake.com",
        firstName: "FINN",
    },
    second: {
        email: "email5fake.com",
        firstName: "JAKE",
    }
}

practitioners2 = [
    {
        email: "email4@fake.com",
        firstName: "FINN",
    },
    {
        email: "email5fake.com",
        firstName: "JAKE",
    }
]

const instance = new TestClass();
instance.createPractitioner({
      email: practitionerEmail,
      firstName: practitionerName,
})

///////// does work

instance.createPractitioners(practitioners2)

///////// does not work but I would like it to work with this variable, but I dunno how to edit the interface or function

instance.createPractitioners(practitioners)
```

Comment: `Object.values(practitioners)`

Comment: Plain text passwords? Brrrr.

Comment: the code is just an example

Comment: I edited the code and description. Can you take a look again @caTS? Your first answer didn't help. The code works but typescript complains

Comment: Your original code was fine. You could've just used `instance.createPractitioners(Object.values(practitioners))`.

Comment: @caTS the code is not OK because it returns errors. It is OK javascript but not OK for typescript.

Answer (score 0):

For the function `instance.createPractitioners` to accept both types of argument (i.e., `practitioners` and `practitioners2`), you have to
set its argument to something like:

```ts
createPractitioners(practitionerData: PractitionerData[] | {[key: string]: PractitionerData})
```

and when you use the argument, you should use `Object.values(practitioners)` as already suggested by @caTS

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApUWYWD2JoAicYcyA3gLABQyyMwUAzmAHJwC2EAXMs1KAHMA3NVoAbOMzacA-Dz6CRNZAAdJjAO44oAEzm8w-EMNHII7OMDHzDi6gF9q1BBMaNkAFQjMAwq-eUyrQIeHwArghg2gAUAJTkprSOVInICFAQxBDomNjAeNDROsRwPKhwUFhwYgA8OZF5BVBEJAB8yAC85PbxgbT9-SEgjDhiEAB0YjgC0QBEoHRhIA14aRlZ9Vi4+FCzsakDQyNjk9NFJePmlmL7QQNpoaMTUzPFJOP0TKwcELcDyal0plIJtGjtGNEVBgGttCCUytCtvkdi04ABtAC6yAAPuQ0QBrCAATxsRgEGIRuVhzRKPQSd0OjxOLzmCxgSxWIDWwOyiLB0EYeycDP6AHpRQ9hmBkG84ABRAAehkwEB0nWQAHkAEYAKwgkXGADdqmFvJC+dTUbElPcxRKjk9Tq8SorlZFVX9bXRtMhokdpVDEMgcDBNbr9WAjSazYGYci4SRYr0Dl6HcyzrHLhYrJ6vYMmc8M9CPgwpD9c-dkv8HP1hWnCzNZh45QBlDxClJUcXdnvILRQfGMahjAMW+NQOXZsRKEeqMdNaQQJSxpFNSfXdWzK5WACMACYAMwHgAC8EJ4xC7Fmy-nO0Xm4AUgBBADScuvwtnK-5TGHEFHVLjowe7CtQ37Uu4XR9P0nzMDw0G2tu1jIFuU4ACynnA56XrMAA0Ka0LB3ycDwswAGIAJIsCweGpPY+F3Iw+p4Do8EEWYU6kUhACsZ4TDhDF5kRi6kc+b60XcyQAlQ4FAXu6poqkCH3EhXHoZh2E4FeglesJPykZR1ESf8Om0MpAyqShPF8ReWnGbppbEdwKFie+pnIMkGJ1qE0qgMwcDLCgXT4BonjeGAfjqHESh+SQgUXusIK3oU5kcdcPCyWuU7uYRjkiXOgELj8DE9MKPblTKODeH22j4sKsUBUgCU8qCEHmoV4J7rc1Dlb2OhVe4IA4NK-b4sgWphNKFE1WEYhqmIwCEsg2DIFENUDn22AABarVtwDuMa-BwFqYy4eNk3INNOhLENyBbTgoVraqK1gFtKCgJAsCICgPrsss2z1VKjX8YlvIdQK7Vxk0jCxEAA)